# JavaFX: save TextArea content to PDF?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, java-8

I am trying to find a way to save the content of a TextArea to PDF. What do you suggest?

Comment: thanks! It seems like the only option.

Comment: If iText seems like the only option, then you haven't googled a lot, as there are more [ways to create PDFs using Java](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+pdf+generator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: thanks! i am really bad with google search terms. I'll look at the generated links.

Answer (score 0):

you need pdfbox-app-2.0.8.jar    from  https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x to run this code . it will crete a pdf with the areatext content in it .

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.Button;
 import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
 import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;


 public class JavaFXApplication5 extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
    Pane pane = new AnchorPane(textarea);

    textarea.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("To pdf");
    btn.setTranslateX(100);
    String text = textarea.getText();
    pane.getChildren().add(btn);

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println(text);

            PDFont font =  PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD ; 
             PDDocument doc    = new PDDocument();
             PDPage page = new PDPage();
             PDPageContentStream content;
            try {
                content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                content.beginText();
                content.moveTextPositionByAmount(300, 400);
                content.setFont(font, 40);
                content.drawString(textarea.getText());

               content.endText();
                content.close();
                doc.addPage(page);
                doc.save("example.pdf");
               } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication5.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(pane);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Text to pdf example");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```